# Does Jenos ultimate damage Androxus with Reversal or Zhin with Counter?

Tags: paladins

Jenos ultimate is a ray that goes through everything, it's described like this :

> [...] unleash your energy in a long range blast that pierces through all obstacles and deals 2400 damage.

Zhin and Androxus have abilities to stop attacks from one direction :

> Counter :
>   If you take an enemy hit to the front of your character you negate any effects of the hit and counter attack with a melee strike dealing 700 damage.
>
> Reversal : 
>   Absorb all shots from the front. After 1.4s, fire a blast dealing 75% of the damage you absorbed.

So which ability wins ? The Jenos ray that pierces everything or the ability to block everything ? (Let's assume that Counter/Reversal is in the correct direction)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, Zhin can't counter it. I'm going to guess Reversal doesn't block it for the same reason Fernando can't block it with a shield (a mistake I've made a few times), likely that it does damage to everyone in the cylinder at once.